# How to create custom keyboard throughout iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios7

Is it possible to create a custom keyboard for iPhone or iPad in iOS 5 or later?
My thinking is I have to create my own keyboard with some icons. And It will popup custom keyboard while beginning the text in textfield.
Is It possible?
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom input view, but within your application only (i.e. you cannot replace the keyboard across the entire device): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2

Essentially you just assign your custom view to the inputView property of a UITextView (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView) and your custom view will be shown when your input becomes the first responder.